# getTextWidths method is giving wrong result

Tags: android, textview, paint, html

There is a problem with some Paint class methods. I should get the width of spanned string given to the TextView. Let's say I'm measuring text at first row. When I measure it programmatically it gives **286**, but the width of the screen is **240**? Maybe someone had such a problem?Any help will be appreciated...

The code for calculating width of spanned text:

```
private int calcWidthSize(CharSequence spannedString, int currentSize) {

    int res = 0;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    float[] a= new float[444];
    paint.setTextSize(currentSize);
    paint.getTextWidths(spannedString,0,spannedString.length(),a);
    for (int num=0;num<a.length;num++){
            res+=(int)a[num];
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.The width of display is in pixels format and equals to 240.Text measure gives us result in dp format